# How to assign yield value to variable

Tags: python, python-asyncio, contextmanager

I was trying to create a dynamic decorator function for both sync and async function and it is working fine, but I cannot use yield value further.

```
def retry(f) -> Any:
    @contextmanager
    def retry_context(*args):
        # response = False
        i = 0
        response_ok = False

        retries = DEFAULT_RETRIES
        status_retries = DEFAULT_STATUS_RETRIES

        retry_count = 0
        while i < retries and response_ok is False:
            retry_count = retry_count+1
            yield response
            i += 1
            if response.status_code not in status_retries:
                response_ok = True
                logger.debug("Response {}".format(response))
        if not response_ok:
            logger.warning("Response ERROR: {}".format(response))
        return response


    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        with retry_context(*args):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    async def async_wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        with retry_context(*args):
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)

    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
        return async_wrapper
    return wrapper
```

I have seen many other answers for assigning value to yield but none is solving my issue, as I also want to use it further. Any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `response` in `wrapper` or `async_wrapper`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this code works properly at all, since as far as I know the `contextmanager` decorator expects only one `yield`, but your `retry_context` can yield multiple times.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes I want to use response in wrapper. You are right `retry_context` can yield multiple times, I just noted that. Can you please tell alternate solution for my situation?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to achieve. What do you want to do with each `yield response` in `wrapper`? Do you want all of them or only the first one or only the last one?

Comment: My main use-case is to call function `f` `retries` number of times but f may be sync or async so I tried to handle that situation with yield but with no luck. Thanks

Comment: And what do you want to do with the various `response` values?

Comment: Well, that's just not how the `@contextmanager` decorator works. It isn't really clear what you are expecting the `@contextmanager`to do for you here, because it is implemented incorrectly (and no try-finally.... which is typically pretty crucial). It also sin't clear where `response` comes from. Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish with the context manager more broadly... it looks like you are just trying to retry, but that doesn't seem like a good use-case for a context manager.

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest using the [`tenacity`](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library instead of implementing retrying from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Context Manager protocol (i.e., the `with` statement ant its associated special methods and helper functions in the `contextlib` module), or "async context manager" as well, in this case - is not designed and cannot be made to work as a "retry" mechanism by itself.

That means: the context manager, either a generator decorated with the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator, or a full-fledged class with an `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods will only, and can only by the way the language works, pass control to the body of the `with` statement a single time. For a `contextmanager` decorated generator, that means it *must* run a `yield` expression a single time in its lifetime.

You should either use an outer `while` loop with a differently designed class, or a ready-made retry library to achieve your goals there.

As for a nice 3rd party library implementing retries with a lot of options and care for edgecases, you can try "tenacity": https://github.com/jd/tenacity

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with tenacity. Thanks everyone for guiding.

```
from tenacity import retry, retry_if_result, stop_after_attempt

retries = 3  
status_retries = (500, 502)

def is_retryable_status_code(response):
    global status_retries
    return response.status_code in status_retries

def retry_with_status(f) -> Any:
    global retries
    @retry(stop = stop_after_attempt(retries), retry=retry_if_result(is_retryable_status_code))
    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    @retry(stop = stop_after_attempt(retries), retry=retry_if_result(is_retryable_status_code))
    async def async_retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return await f(*args, **kwargs)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        global retries, status_retries
        if 'retry' in dir(args[0]) and 'status_retries' in dir(args[0]):
            retries = args[0].retries
            status_retries = args[0].status_retries

        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
            return async_retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```